# First order nonlinear differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem trying to solve this differential equation. Could someone please help me?
$$x(y'^2+e^{2y})+2y'=0$$

I tried the following:

- $x(y'+e^y)^2-2y'e^y+2y'=0$, set $u=e^y+y$.
- Then $u'=y'+e^y\cdot y'$.

Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.....

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: You missed a factor $x$ in $-2xy'e^y$.

Comment: I don't know if it is closer to a solution, but the substitution $u = e^{-y}$ gives the differential equation $$x(u'^2+1)-2uu' = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $$v(x) = \frac{e^{-y}}{x}$$ which simplifies the equation to

$$x^2v'^2+1-v^2=0$$

This has the constant solutions $v = \pm 1$ which means we get the solution

$$y = -\log|x|$$

for free. The "nonconstant" solutions can be found by separation of variables

$$\frac{v'}{\sqrt{v^2-1}}=\pm\frac{1}{|x|} \implies \cosh^{-1}(|v|) = \pm\log(C|x|)$$

$$\implies v = Cx+(4Cx)^{-1}$$

and transforming back to $y$ gives us

$$y = -\log\left(Cx^2+\frac{1}{4C}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

#### Addendum/Variant to the answer of Ninad Munshi

Taking the derivative of the first $v$ equation gives
$$2v'(x^2v''+xv'-v)=0$$
which outside of constant segments gives an Euler-Cauchy equation with characteristic polynomial $$0=m(m-1)+m-1=(m+1)(m-1).$$ The constants in $$v(x)=Cx+Dx^{-1}$$ are then connected by the original equation,
$$(Cx-Dx^{-1})^2+1-(Cx+Dx^{-1})=0\iff 4CD=1.$$